# Reading lines from input Python

Tags: python

Could you tell me how to read all the lines from the input?

I'm trying to get information using:

```
data = input()
```

Input:

```
5
1
22:13:56-22:13:55
1
00:00:00-23:59:59
1
23:59:59-00:00:00
2
00:00:00-23:59:59
00:00:00-23:59:59
2
13:44:59-13:44:59
13:45:00-13:45:00
```

But the data list contains only '5'

Comment: Is your input a file? Are you typing this?

Comment: `while input(): pass`

Comment: @Ftagliacarne, the input is not a file. I'm typing this in the console

Answer (score 1):

You can read the input in loop and append it to some string. Example:

```py
data = ''
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == 'q':
        break
    data += line
```

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of understanding **added input statement** also.

**Code snippet:**

```
no_of_testcases=int(input("Enter the no_of_testcase: "))
data=[]
for i in range(no_of_testcases):
    n=int(input("Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: "))
    for j in range(n):
        data.append(input("Interval: "))

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the no_of_testcase: 5
Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: 1
Interval: 22:13:56-22:13:55
Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: 1
Interval: 00:00:00-23:59:59
Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: 1
Interval: 23:59:59-00:00:00
Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: 2
Interval: 00:00:00-23:59:59
Interval: 00:00:00-23:59:59
Enter how many time interval you wanted to enter: 2
Interval: 13:44:59-13:44:59
Interval: 13:45:00-13:45:00
['22:13:56-22:13:55', '00:00:00-23:59:59', '23:59:59-00:00:00', '00:00:00-23:59:59', '00:00:00-23:59:59', '13:44:59-13:44:59', '13:45:00-13:45:00']
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to copy this entire structure and read it as a whole, that is, without entering it separately?

Comment: if it is in file than the answer is given by the stack member.. but if it is in console i don't think so we can do that..! @Tivasic